# Should performance/integration tests be considered modules in a multi-module Maven project?

Tags: maven, maven-3

In a Maven multi-module project, should I consider the integration/performance tests projects also as modules?

```
multi-module-project
  ├── module-war
  ├── some-other-module
  └── etc...

Should I include?
  └── performance-tests
```

ADD:

What if these tests take hours to finish?

What if they require real servers running, like a JBoss cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest in case of a web application to have a separate module as you suggested. I see performance tests as a kind of integration tests. Like this:

```
multi-module-project
  ├── module-war
  ├── some-other-module
  └── integration-tests
  └── performance-tests
  └── etc...
```

EDIT:

As mentioned in the comments: "You can control the execution of the integration test by a profile"

Comment: but what if these tests take hours to complete? I add some lines to que original question

Comment: You can control the execution of the integration test by a profile. And the best thing to put such things into a Continuous Integration environment like Hudson/Jenkins etc.

Comment: +1: I agree with Karl-Heinz as this is what I normally do. Profiles are a good thing and if your integration tests execute in timely fashion, having them in the same project is fine. However, if your tests are also performance tests or take a significant amount of time, it only makes sense to have a separate project for them. You can add a dependency in your integration-tests to `module-war` or `some-other-module` (which I presume is already a dependency of `module-war`). This way when you add these projects to your CI, it will trigger the builds as necessary.

Comment: @carlspring if I can ignore them or not by using Profiles when building, do you still think they shouldn't be a module? If they take too long or depend on external resources, they could be ignored by default in a simple "mvn clean install" and activated by a -PintegrationTests

Comment: @khmarbaise your profile solution complements your answer. If you could accept the edit I just made

Comment: Don't put your `*-tests` modules in the same aggregator. Make them separate modules. This way you don't need to have profiles or anything and the CI can run them for you. Nice, simple and clean.

Comment: If you have a separate module you have the overhead of holding them in sync with the application. So better is having them in the same reactor which means same version etc. In CI you usually need a separate job for running integration tests so no problem activating a profile.

Comment: The profile solution is non-portable: if you define the `<modules/>` in a profile, that will work, but during releases you will have a load of fun.

Comment: I haven't written to put the modules into a profile, cause i know that you will run in trouble during the release. I would put the execution part in the module into a profile.